# React Native: can't get the data but the data can be seen i using console log

Tags: react-native

im still new on using react native and i have the problem like this:
im trying to get the data from this api which is https://covid19.mathdro.id/api
just to get the values for the death patients but i got nothing in the app it doesn't show the value of the deaths but in the console it show both the value and details
here are the code that i use:

```
class Deaths extends React.Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        Dead: [
        ],
        refreshing: false
    }

}

}
renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <View>
        <Text>{item.value}</Text>
        <Text>{item.detail}</Text></View>

)


onRefresh = () => {
    this.getDataApi();

}

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getDataApi();
}

getDataApi = async () =>{
    this.setState({ refreshing: true})
    const response = await fetch('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/')
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({Dead: json.deaths, refreshing: false})
}

render(){
    console.log(this.state.Dead)
    return(
        <View>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.Dead}
                keyExtractor={item => item.deaths.toString()}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                refreshing = {this.state.refreshing}
                onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not displaying as you need to pass array to the FlatList but you were passing an object, Here in your case you don't require FlatList, you can directly do like this:

```
return (
    <View>
       <Text>{this.state.Dead.detail}</Text>
       <Text>{this.state.Dead.value}</Text>
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatlist doesn't refresh with state change until you pass the state as `extraData` to your flatlist

```
<FlatList
  ...
  extraData={this.state}
/>
```

You can check it in the documentation.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array to the `data` prop of `FlatList`. In the response, `deaths` is not an array:

```
"deaths":{"value":257818,"detail":"https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/deaths"}
```